# Observe values not seen in other observers

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an observable that emits unique values e.g.

```cs
var source=Observable.Range(1,100).Publish();
source.Connect();
```

I want to observe its values from e.g.  two observers but each observer to get notified only for values not seen in other observers.

So if first observer contains the value 10 the second observer should never get notified for the 10 value.

**Update**

I chose @Asti`s answer cause it was first and although buggy it pointed to the right direction and up-voted @Shlomo's answer. Too bad I cannot accept both answers as @Shlomo answer was more correct and I really appreciate all his help we get on this tag.

Comment: It's not a great idea to call `.Publish()` on `Observable.Range(1,100)` otherwise it only runs once ever no matter how many subscribers come along later.

Comment: thanks I just wanted to express a hot observable rather one that emit everything on each subscription. I guess a better idea would be to add some delay between emits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observables aren't supposed to behave differently for different observers; a better approach would be to give each observer its own filtered observable.

That being said, if your constraints require that you need this behavior in a single observable - we can use a Round-Robin method.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        for (; ; )
            foreach (var item in source.ToArray())
                yield return item;
    }

    public static IObservable<T> RoundRobin<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        var subscribers = new List<IObserver<T>>();
        var shared = source
            .Zip(subscribers.Repeat(), (value, observer) => (value, observer))
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();

        return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
        {
            subscribers.Add(observer);
            var subscription = 
                shared
                .Where(pair => pair.observer == observer)
                .Select(pair => pair.value)
                .Subscribe(observer);

            var dispose = Disposable.Create(() => subscribers.Remove(observer));
            return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, dispose);
        });
    }
```

Usage:

```
var source = Observable.Range(1, 100).Publish();
var dist = source.RoundRobin();
dist.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"One sees {i}"));
dist.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"Two sees {i}"));

source.Connect();
```

Result:

```
One sees 1
Two sees 2
One sees 3
Two sees 4
One sees 5
Two sees 6
One sees 7
Two sees 8
One sees 9
Two sees 10
```

If you already have a list of observers, the code becomes much simpler.

Comment: Great answer! Just a note: the `Repeat` extension method is included in the [`System.Interactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) package.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote this first, then realized that he might say there's no method called `Repeat`, so I wrote it in. It's happened before :D

Comment: Also, there's a slight difference in behavior with `Repeat` in `EnumerableEx`. I force eval with `ToArray()` otherwise the list might throw up a "collection was modified while enumerating" error.

Comment: Yes, it would be a problem if another subscriber was added after `source.Connect()`. Alternatively you could chain `ToArray` and `Repeat`: `subscribers.ToArray().Repeat()`.

Comment: Actually no, your `Repeat` method defers from `.ToArray().Repeat()` in that it takes a new snapshot of the source `IEnumerable` on every repetition. Which will allow a new subscriber to receive notifications among the old subscribers. Clever!

Comment: Thanks Theodor! I learn a bunch of stuff from your answers too! :)

Comment: There's a bug in this, see my answer.

Comment: @Shlomo Great find!

Comment: Edited mine. It's because `Zip` doesn't actually grab the enumerator first, so we have to share the stream. Very interesting [comment in the source](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/802cc413eb3befdb329256d7f3682aaa5996cbd1/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/Zip.cs#L291).

Comment: This is a buggy implementation with a race condition. Note the testing scenario in the next comment which misses 1 due to cached observers list in ToArray()

Comment: var sequence = Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                .RoundRobin();

            var first = sequence.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            var second = sequence.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            
            Thread.Sleep(550);
            
            second.Dispose();

            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @Asti tagging you here

Comment: I think that's acceptable in a load-balancing scenario? It's not like the message is skipped.
Should we make the subscribe thread-safe then?

Comment: @Asti this is exactly that happened - message #1 was skipped and lost

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: @Asti fixed his bug, and I fixed mine based on his answer. Our answers are now largely similar. I have an idea how to do a purely reactive one, if I have time I'll post that later.

Fixed code:

```
public static IObservable<T> RoundRobin2<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    var subscribers = new BehaviorSubject<ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>>(ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>.Empty);
    ImmutableList<IObserver<T>> latest = ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>.Empty;
    subscribers.Subscribe(l => latest = l);

    var shared = source
            .Select((v, i) => (v, i))
            .WithLatestFrom(subscribers, (t, s) => (t.v, t.i, s))
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        subscribers.OnNext(latest.Add(observer));
        var dispose = Disposable.Create(() => subscribers.OnNext(latest.Remove(observer)));

        var sub = shared
            .Where(t => t.i % t.s.Count == t.s.FindIndex(o => o == observer))
            .Select(t => t.v)
            .Subscribe(observer);

        return new CompositeDisposable(dispose, sub);
    });
}
```

---

**Original answer**:
I upvoted @Asti's answer, because he's largely correct: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. And his answer largely works, but it's subject to a bug:

This works fine:

```
var source = Observable.Range(1, 20).Publish();
var dist = source.RoundRobin();
dist.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"One sees {i}"));
dist.Take(1).Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"Two sees {i}"));
```

This doesn't:

```
var source = Observable.Range(1, 20).Publish();
var dist = source.RoundRobin();
dist.Take(1).Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"One sees {i}"));
dist.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"Two sees {i}"));
```

Output is:

```
One sees 1
Two sees 1
Two sees 2
Two sees 3
Two sees 4
...
```

I first thought the bug is [Halloween related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem), but now I'm not sure. The `.ToArray()` in `Repeat` should take care of that. I also wrote a pure-ish observable implementation which has the same bug. This implementation doesn't guarantee a perfect Round Robin, but that wasn't in the question:

```
public static IObservable<T> RoundRobin2<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    var subscribers = new BehaviorSubject<ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>>(ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>.Empty);
    ImmutableList<IObserver<T>> latest = ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>.Empty;
    subscribers.Subscribe(l => latest = l);

    var shared = source
            .Select((v, i) => (v, i))
            .WithLatestFrom(subscribers, (t, s) => (t.v, t.i, s))
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        subscribers.OnNext(latest.Add(observer));
        var dispose = Disposable.Create(() => subscribers.OnNext(latest.Remove(observer)));

        var sub = shared
            .Where(t => t.i % t.s.Count == t.s.FindIndex(o => o == observer))
            .Select(t => t.v)
            .Subscribe(observer);

        return new CompositeDisposable(dispose, sub);
    });
}
```

Comment: great answers thnks both @Shlomo and @Asti, a small clarification about the `perfect Round-Robin` is most welcomed

Comment: Because the round-robin technique relies on a simple mod operation, where the number of subscribers can change at any time, there's no guarantee that an observer won't miss his turn on occasion. Ultimately not that big a problem.

Comment: An item won't be missed, but an observer may be skipped over, which according to your question isn't that big a problem.

Comment: I think this could probably be done probably with some sort of windowing in Rx, but I can see the perf being bad. I think the best way for perf is in TPL Dataflow, and not Rx.

Comment: @Asti if you have spare upvotes, you could also upvote the question. It's a good one! :-)

Comment: Added a dataflow based answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple distributed queue implementation using TPL Dataflow. But with respect to different observers not seeing the same value, there's little chance of it behaving incorrectly. It's not round-robin, but actually has back-pressure semantics.

```
    public static IObservable<T> Distribute<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<T>();
        source.Subscribe(buffer.AsObserver());             
        return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
            buffer.LinkTo(new ActionBlock<T>(observer.OnNext, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1 })
        );
    }
```

Output

```
One sees 1
Two sees 2
One sees 3
Two sees 4
One sees 5
One sees 6
One sees 7
One sees 8
One sees 9
One sees 10
```

I might prefer skipping Rx entirely and just using TPL Dataflow.